# Catch network errors in R using trycatch

Tags: r, networking

I'm using two services decode_short_url (twitteR package) and get_url (socialmediamineR package) to expand short url's in R. My function urltry() given below tries to expand url and catch all types of possible errors.

```
#install.packages("twitteR")
#install.packages("SocialMediaMineR")
library(twitteR)
library(SocialMediaMineR)

urltry <- function(x) {    
    tryCatch(
        { x <- decode_short_url(x)  },
        error = function(e)
        {
          x <- urltryfail(x)
          return(x)
        }   
    )  
}    

urltryfail <- function(x) {    
    tryCatch(
    {
    x <- get_url(x, sleep.time = 1, return.df = T)
    x <- as.character(x$resolvedURL)  },
    error = function(e)
        {
          return(x)
        },
    finally ={ x }  
    )  
}
```

But when decode_short_url and get_url fails due to network error. I'm getting a return value

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to
>   host\n

from the function urltry() instead of catching the error and returning the short url.

[sample data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=12276896078830349367)

Comment: Any special packages you're using? How about a working example so that we can try it against?

Comment: Hello @RomanLuštrik , Thanks for your suggestion I have added the required packages in the above code. You will be able  able to run the function now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the **get_url()** function in the SocialMediaMineR package. It catches the error when it is returned from the httr package internally if the URL is unresolvable. And so the error never reaches your tryCatch function. The get_url always returns a valid dataframe.
So also if the URL is not valid you always get a dataframe with the columns **originalURL** and **resolvedURL** but the resolvedURL column contains the error message.

```
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| originalURL | resolvedURL                                                                       |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sdgsdg      | Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE),: \n,Could not resolve host: http\n |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So you basically have to options:

1:)
You check if the returned dataframe contains the phrase "Error in function" in the resolvedURL column. And if yes you just use the originalURL

2:)
You copy-paste the code from the get_url() function from the SocialMediaMineR and modify it a little bit. You just have to remove the try() around HEAD(x)$url. Now if the get_url function is called with an unresolvable URL it just breaks and throws an error which will make your tryCatch function actually recognise it and jump to the error function you defined in your code.

```
get_url <-
function(links, sleep.time=0, return.df=F){
    final_url <- function(x) HEAD(x)$url
    final_url2 <- function(x) {
        Sys.sleep(sleep.time)
        cat(".")
        final_url(x)
    }
    if(return.df==F) { 
        return(vapply(links, final_url2, character(1)))
    } else {
        temp <- vapply(links, final_url2, character(1))
        url.result <- data.frame(originalURL=names(temp), resolvedURL=as.character(temp))
        return(url.result)
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have checked the get_url source code. Anyway thanks a lot. :)